# Java Thread Stuck Wildfly 10.1 Consuming 100% CPU (10 Core)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, servlet-filters, wildfly-10

We have recently moved from Jboss 4 to Wildfly 10.1 and Java 1.6 to 1.8.
We are facing many issue regarding CPU utilization, for instance below thread is running from last 16 hours and not ending. There are two thread like this and both are consuming 16% cpu and increasing.

We have web application every request land on this filter because of this CPU utilisation increased to 100%.

In our project we are using **java.nio.channels** but while running on wildfly it is taking 
**org.xnio.channels.Channels**.

On jboss 4 everything working fine and CPU utilisation not going above 200%.

```
"default task-39" #252 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7d8803f800 nid=0x4c8f runnable [0x00007f7e072f2000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Channels.java:158)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:283)
at io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.writeBuffer(BlockingSenderImpl.java:190)
at io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.send(BlockingSenderImpl.java:71)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachedResource.serve(CachedResource.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.serveFileBlocking(DefaultServlet.java:332)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:180)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at com.eko.framework.MifosNGFilter.doNormal(MifosNGFilter.java:283)
at com.eko.framework.MifosNGFilter.doFilter(MifosNGFilter.java:121)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.eko.framework.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.eko.framework.URLSessionFilter.doFilter(URLSessionFilter.java:38)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.mifos.framework.security.util.FileNameFilter.doFilter(FileNameFilter.java:59)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We are just performing basic filter and thread not getting end.
Below is the java code :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


    String reqUri = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI();
    String reqMethod = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getParameter("method");
    String requestText = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getParameter("requestText");
    String originatioAddress = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getParameter("originationAddress");

    Date requestTime = new Date();
    HttpSession httpSession = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession(false);
    UserContext userContext = null;
    if (httpSession != null) {
        userContext = (UserContext) httpSession
                .getAttribute(Constants.USERCONTEXT);
    }

    try {

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
        resp.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
        resp.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1);
        resp.setHeader("X-Powered-By", null);
        resp.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession().getId() 
                 +
                 "; _ga=" + 
                ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession().getAttribute("_ga")
                + "; Path=" + 
        ((HttpServletRequest) req).getContextPath()      
                +
                 "; httpOnly; secure;" );

        doNormal(chain, req, res);

    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.warn(t, t);
    }
}

private void doNormal(FilterChain chain, ServletRequest req,
        ServletResponse res) throws ServletException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error(t, t);
        throw new ServletException(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the doNormal method ? This is not a Filter implementation code so you don't really show us the code. Also there are quite a few filters there, maybe those are not releasing the outputStream or something like that

Comment: @ehsavoie added complete code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildfly 10.1 Consuming All Cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539041/wildfly-10-1-consuming-all-cores)

Comment: What happens if you manipulate the response after doNormal instead of before ?

Comment: @ROHIT Could you solve your problem and if so how?

Comment: @Lonzak I was unable to solve the issue, we had to move back to jboss 4.